# Suppose that every map $S^1 \to X$ extends to a map $D^2 \to X$. Show that this implies that every map $S^1 \to X$ is homotopic to a constant map.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Suppose that every map $S^1 \to X$ extends to a map $D^2 \to X$. Show that this implies that every map $S^1 \to X$ is homotopic to a constant map.

Consider $f:S^1 \to X$, then by our assumption there exists $g:D^2 \to X$ such that $g \mid_{S^1} = f$. Now since $D^2 \approx C(S^1)$, where $C(S^1)=(S^1 \times I )/(S^1 \times \{1\})$ we can consider $\tilde{g}: C(S^1)\to X$ which restricts $\tilde{g} \mid_{S^1 \times \{0\}}=f$ when we identify $x \in S^1$ and $(x,0) \in S^1 \times \{0\}$(which I think we can do?).

Now we also have the quotient map $q :S^1 \times I \to C(S^1)$ which we can use to define $h:=\tilde g \circ q :S^1 \times I \to X$ and note that $$h(x,0)=\tilde g(q(x,0))=\tilde g(\{x,0\})=f$$ and $$h(x,1)=\tilde g(q(x,1))=\tilde g (\{x,1\})$$ which is constant as $q(x,1)$ is constant (it maps to the vertex of the cone all of $S^1 \times I$)

Also the continuity of $h$ follows from the continuity of $\tilde g$ and $q$. Thus $h$ is a homotopy from $f$ to a constant map.

Are there any "holes" in the arguments here? I'm unsure about the consideration of $\tilde g$.